# C++言語での入力終わりまでcinで入力を受け付ける方法

Tags: c++, shell

C++で下記のことで困っています。
入力が終わったら、while文をぬけたいのですがどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

### インプット

1 3 8 9

### 期待する挙動

g++でコンパイルして、./a.outとしてコンソール上で実行。
9を入力してエンターを押したら下記のように出力されるプログラムが終了すること。

1
3
8
9

### 困っていること

9を入力してエンターを押しても、まだ入力を受け付けた状態になってしまい、whileループを抜けられない

### コード

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string s;
  while(cin >> s) {
    cout << s << endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

プログラムに入力が終了したこと(EOF: end of file)を知らせる必要があります。

Windowsの場合、<kbd>Control+z</kbd>を入力するとEOFになります。
MacやLinuxの場合は、<kbd>Control+d</kbd>を入力するとEOFになります。

参考: [How to enter the value of EOF in the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968558/how-to-enter-the-value-of-eof-in-the-terminal?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: ありがとうございます！まさにこれで解決です！